# javascript simple authentication

Tags: javascript, html

Excuse me for such a simple questions. I tried google by myself with no luck and that's why asking for help here. What's wrong about my auth() code?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script>
function checkform(f) {
  var errMSG = "";             
  for (var i = 0; i<f.elements.length; i++) 
    if (null!=f.elements[i].getAttribute("required")) 
        if (isEmpty(f.elements[i].value))
            errMSG += "  " + f.elements[i].pass + "\n";   
        if ("" != errMSG) {
            alert("Не заполнены обязательные поля:\n" + errMSG);
            return false;
        }
}
function isEmpty(str) {
   for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
      if (" " != str.charAt(i))
          return false;
      return true;
}
function auth(){
var admin_email = "123@123.123"
var admin_password = "S3cur3Passw0rd"
if(document.pass.GetElemetnById.value() == admin_password && document.email.GetElemetnById.value()== admin_email)
document.writeln('Acess granted')
else document.writeln('Acess denied')
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form onSubmit = "return checkform(this)">
<table>
<tr>
<td>email</td><td><input type="text" name="email" required></td></tr>
<tr><td>пароль</td><td><input type="text" name="pass" required></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit"></td><td>
</table>
</form>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

So nothing really happens after submitting the form that contains password and login

Comment: you _have_ to authenticate on the server side...

Comment: This is terrifying.  If you put the administrator email and password in JavaScript, you might as well just post the contents of whatever you are trying to "secure."  It's right out there for anyone to take it!

Answer (score 1):

Do not authenticate in JavaScript, and ***absolutely never*** put a password in your JavaScript.  This is as secure as leaving your keys in your car's ignition and the driver's door open: anyone can see the way in, and anyone can run away with your stuff.

Always authenticate on the server side, and don't try to "roll your own" login system, either.  Go with proven algorithms.